# How to access and extend ES7 parent class attributes at declare time in sub-class body?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-next

Considering this class

```
class BasePage extends Component {
  state = {
    locale: 'en'
  };

  render() {
    return (<div>{ this.state.locale }</div>);
  }
}
```

How can I declare a sub-class that will also declare a `state` attribute that will not override the parent class attribute, but will extend it?

```
class FooPage extends BasePage {
  state = Object.assign( ?super.state, {
    foo: 'Hello'
  });

  render() {
    return (<div>{ this.state.locale } : { this.state.foo }</div>);
  }
}
```

Obviously, `super.state` does not work, and `BasePage.prototype.state` does not exist either.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to answer it from a plain JS perspective (but same concept applies to React if you're using React).

In order for you to use base's props, you'd need to do so in the child's constructor:

```
class BasePage {
  state = {
    locale: 'en'
  }; 
}

class FooPage extends BasePage {
  constructor() {
    super();  // can't access this props without calling super first

    // this.state refers to super's state prop. We simply extend it using Object.assign.
    this.state = Object.assign(this.state, {
      foo: 'Hello'
    });
  }  

  render() {
    const { locale, foo } = this.state;
    console.log({ locale, foo });  // prints { locale: 'en', foo: 'Hello' }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@mrchief/UrbanLiveTrace

Note about React: Since React is built on top of plain JS, the same concepts (i.e. calling `super` first applies there as well).

Alternatively, if you don't like the constructor approach, you can achieve similar effect via getters:

```
class BasePage {
  get state()  {
    return { locale: 'en' }
  } 
}

class FooPage extends BasePage {
  get state()  {
    return Object.assign(super.state, {
      foo: 'Hello'
    })
  }  

  render() {
    const { locale, foo } = this.state;
    console.log({ locale, foo });  // prints { locale: 'en', foo: 'Hello' }
  }
}
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@mrchief/GloriousGainsboroOpensoundsystem

Comment: Thanks. I actually ended up doing the first example.